# A href onclick append to input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a message system and so far it's almost done, just the Send message needs a small edit. I have created a live search for the receiver and it's working, everything is showing but I want to make an on click function to append the name of the receiver into the input.

[image: example image]

Or is there any way to change the placeholder while typing the username ?

This is the autocomplete script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#to input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("engine/includes/message_to_autocomplete.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });


    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents("#to").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});
```

And it returns: `$row['username']` as shown onto the image.

Comment: have you tried jquery autocomplete? refer https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to give us a proper problem description - a mere “I want” does not qualify as one. Show what you have tried, and explain what _exactly_ you are struggling with.

Comment: This what I want to do is when I click on the name which is suggested the name will go to the input box .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to reinvent the wheel. Since you are already using jquery, you can try [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

```js
$(function() {
    var names = ["Austin", "Bryson", "Claudia", "David", "Eve", "Fabio", "Garry", "Helen"];

    $("#to").autocomplete({ source: names });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="to" type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
```

As for changing the placeholder, there is a library called [typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) and you can find plenty of demos [here](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/)